# Recieving the following error while trying to comment out Apex Trigger: "Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '<EOF>'. at line 65 column 1 "

Tags: apex, trigger, class, admin, comments

I'm a point and click admin with little Apex experience in need of some assitance. I am attempting to Comment out and Apex Class in my Organization, however when attempting to update the Trigger in sandbox I receive the following error message: "Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token ''. at line 65 column 1"

Here is a snip of my code: [image]

Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated. I'd rather not have to overpay a consultant to take care of this.

Comment: Please include your code as *text* not an image. Also, it does not appear you have taken any steps to comment it out. Where specifically do you think you commented out the trigger body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To comment out this trigger so that it does nothing and contains no references to any classes, insert on line 4:
/*
and on line 63:
*/